# Creation of Kernel Modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have to create a linux driver for the first time and I have some questions which I don't found convenient answer. My goal is to create a PWM driver, I already succeed to create a driver and work with him thank's to IOCTL but I want do two more things for which one I have no idea how do that.

The first thing : I want the driver be load at boot, I read a lot of things about probe function but I don't understand how it's work, some people talk about module-load.r so what is the best way to do that ?

The second thing : I have to create many drivers for each device tree declaration of device which use this drivers, but how create dynamically a file in /dev/ for each instances ?

I don't know if it's clear but I give the code and the device tree :

```
#define WR_DUTYCYCLE _IOW('a', 1, int32_t *)
#define WR_FREQ _IOW('a', 2, int32_t *)
#define RD_DUTYCYCLE _IOR('a', 3, int32_t *)
#define RD_FREQ _IOR('a', 4, int32_t *)

#define DEV_CLASS_MODE ((umode_t)(S_IRUGO|S_IWUGO))

/* Meta Information */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Benjamin CLEMENT");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Generate a PWM with chosen DUTY CYCLE and FREQUENCY");

/* Variables for device and device class */
static dev_t my_device_nr;
static struct class *my_class;
static struct cdev my_device;

static struct platform_device *pdev;
unsigned long *base_addr;
unsigned long *base_addr;

#define DRIVER_NAME "pwm"
#define DRIVER_CLASS "MyModuleClass"


/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the device file is opened
 */
static int driver_open(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance) {
    printk("dev_nr - open was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the device file is opened
 */

static int driver_close(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance) {
    printk("dev_nr - close was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module use IOCTL for write or read
 */

static long int my_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned cmd, unsigned long arg){
    
    long int back;                                                                      //Looking for the register
    char *path = "/";                                            
    struct device_node *dt_node;  
    dt_node = of_find_node_by_path(path);
    struct device_node *dt_pwm;
    u32 reg[4]; 
    
    //Looking for base_adress
    if (!dt_node) {                                                              
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to find node by path: %s.\n");                   
    } else {                                                                     
            dt_pwm = of_find_node_by_name(dt_node, file->f_path.dentry->d_iname);
            if (!dt_pwm) {                                                              
                printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to find node pwm: %s.\n");                   
            }
            else{
                of_property_read_u32_array(dt_pwm, "reg", reg, 4);
                //printk("Adress GPIO1 : %x", reg[1]); 
                //printk("ADRESS GPIO2 : %x", reg[1] + 8);
            }
    }
    switch(cmd){
        case WR_DUTYCYCLE: 
            writel(arg, ioremap(reg[1], 8));
            //printk("test wrdc %lu\n", arg);
            back = 0;
            break;
        case WR_FREQ:
            writel(arg, ioremap(reg[1] + 8, 8));
            back = 0;
            break;
        case RD_DUTYCYCLE:
            back = readl(ioremap(reg[1], 8));
            printk("Valeur ecrite dc : %d", back);
            break;
        case RD_FREQ:
            back = readl(ioremap(reg[1] + 8, 8));
            printk("Valeur ecrite : %d", back);
            break;
    }
    return back;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = driver_open,
    .release = driver_close,
    .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
};

/**
 * @brief This function is called at init for permit all users to call this drivers
 */

static char *mydevnode(struct device *dev, umode_t *mode)
  {
     if (mode)
         *mode = DEV_CLASS_MODE;; 
     return NULL;
 }

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is loaded into the kernel
 */
 
 
 
static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
    int retval;
    printk("Hello, Kernel! test2\n");

    /* Allocate a device nr */
    if(alloc_chrdev_region(&my_device_nr, 0, 1, DRIVER_NAME) < 0) {
        printk("Device Nr. could not be allocated!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk("read_write - Device Nr. Major: %d, Minor: %d was registered!\n", my_device_nr >> 20, my_device_nr && 0xfffff);

    /* Create device class */
    if((my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, DRIVER_CLASS)) == NULL) {
        printk("Device class can not be created!\n");
        goto ClassError;
    }

    //Activate for all users
    my_class->devnode = mydevnode;
    
    /* create device file */
    if(device_create(my_class, NULL, my_device_nr, NULL, DRIVER_NAME) == NULL){
        printk("Can not create device file!\n");
        goto FileError;
    }
    /* Initialize device file */
    cdev_init(&my_device, &fops);

    /* Registering device to kernel */
    if(cdev_add(&my_device, my_device_nr, 1) == -1) {
        printk("Registering of device to kernel failed!\n");
        goto AddError;
    }
    
    return 0;
AddError:
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
FileError:
    class_destroy(my_class);
ClassError:
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    return -1;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is removed from the kernel
 */
static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    cdev_del(&my_device);
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
    class_destroy(my_class);
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    printk("Goodbye, Kernel\n");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);
```

And my concerning device tree is this :

```
amba_pl@0 {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        ranges ;
            pwm1@80000000 {
            #gpio-cells = <3>;
            clock-names = "s_axi_aclk";
            clocks = <&zynqmp_clk 71>;
            compatible = "pwm";
            gpio-controller ;
            reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x0>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x1>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
        };
            pwm0@80010000 {
            #gpio-cells = <3>;
            clock-names = "s_axi_aclk";
            clocks = <&zynqmp_clk 71>;
            compatible = "pwm";
            gpio-controller ;
            reg = <0x0 0x80010000 0x0 0x10000>;
            xlnx,all-inputs = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-inputs-2 = <0x0>;
            xlnx,all-outputs = <0x1>;
            xlnx,all-outputs-2 = <0x1>;
            xlnx,dout-default = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,dout-default-2 = <0x00000000>;
            xlnx,gpio-width = <0x8>;
            xlnx,gpio2-width = <0x20>;
            xlnx,interrupt-present = <0x0>;
            xlnx,is-dual = <0x1>;
            xlnx,tri-default = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
            xlnx,tri-default-2 = <0xFFFFFFFF>;
        };
    };
```

Thank's for any help !

Answer (score 0):

> The first thing : I want the driver be load at boot, I read a lot of things about probe function but I don't understand how it's work, some people talk about module-load.r so what is the best way to do that ?

You probably mean the `/etc/modules-load.d/` directory.

If a kernel module is not loaded automatically because of hardware probing or because some other module depends on it, you can configure a module to be loaded at boot time by creating a text file in that directory, containing the name(s) of module(s) you wish to be loaded, one name per line. You can name the file however you wish, but it has to have a `.conf` suffix.

Your second thing is [a programming question about device driver development](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic), and so it should be placed in [Stack Overflow.SE](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, so in my case it's better to create a probe function or use this directory ?